# React Native Code not running, stuck with error - Connection to localhost port 8081 [tcp/sunproxyadmin] succeeded

Tags: react-native

There is no error given but the code is not built or run as well it is stuck with the following line in terminal

react native run stuck after Connection to localhost port 8081 [tcp/sunproxyadmin] succeeded!

Answer (score 2):

Try killing all your node server with this command:

```
killall -9 node
```

After try again building and running with this command:

```
yarn start &react-native run-ios
```

Comment: Please, accept the answer for everyone else who faces the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

It happens mostly when you're using real device for testing. The quickest solution to this is to close the node server window and re-run `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`
If this doesn't help close all terminal windows and restart everything.
If this is what you're looking for i hope it helps or you need to provide more details about the problem like screen shot or error message.

Comment: This did not help in my case.